# How to compile an Angular template to text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to compile an AngularJS template to plain text. I.e. I want to get what you would get by reading the inner HTML of a template rendered in the DOM on the page. But without actually rendering the template to the page.

I have tried using `$compile` like this

```
$compile(template)($scope).html()
```

But it does not seem to work as expected as demonstrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paldepind/4YtLu/7/). The result both in the jsFiddle and in my project is nothing but a comment inserted by Angular.

What is the proper way to compile an Angular template and getting the result back as an HTML string?

In case anyone are curious why I need to do this: The rendered HTML will be sent to the backend which converts it to a pdf-file that is sent back again.

Comment: Have you tried innerhtml? Does $compile return a jQlite object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the final output with the scope applied to the view I believe you have to wait until the `$digest` call is completed.

I updated the fiddle to write the finished HTML to the console.  I used a setTimeout() to wait until the `$digest` call was completed and it displayed the actual result that would be displayed in the HTML.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjmeyers/FHNus/)

Comment: I didn't know about `$digest`. Your solution does indeed work but it is kinda a hack. I can't assume that the compile will always happen in under a second.

Comment: I was using the `setTimeout` to demonstrate that if you hold onto the element until after the $digest is completed that the element will be rendered regardless of if it is in the DOM or not.  You can call `$scope.$apply();` directly and you can get the html that way.  You will see an error in the log as well, but it isn't fatal.  I updated the fiddle to do this.

Comment: +1. Andy's solution is correct given this use case. But shouldn't trigger digest loop directly, should just use setTimeout(..., 0) to avoid 2 digest loops (one in code & one by AngularJS after bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do. The isolated scope is optional I suppose, but any model you have will need to be a part of a `Scope`:

```js
var template = '<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>',
    element = angular.element(template ),
    scope = $rootScope.$new(true); //isolated scope

scope.items = ['foo', 'bar', 'frob'];

// apply bindings!
$compile(template)(scope);

var html = template[0].outerHTML;
```